# angularjs import makes html page not functional

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have very simple code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/app.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js" />
  </head>
  <body>
    asdfasdf
    {{1+2}}
  </body>
</html>
```

and I'm pretty sure everything is pointing to the right directory. My app.js is:

```
( function () {

  var app = angular.module( 'app' , [] );

}) ();
```

However, opening index.html on localhost all I can see is a blank page but when I delete the lines

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js" />
```

I get a page that says "asdfasdf {{1+2}}" How can I get angular working? Is there a big mistake I'm making somewhere?

Comment: There should be an error in your console, hit F12, reload page and see what it is.

Comment: There will be no error in the console because your script tags are self-closing, and as pointed out below they shouldn't be. The network tab in your dev tools would show it NOT loading the script files though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script tags must have an end tag. They cannot be self-terminating.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
```